# How to replace some strings in a file on the other?

Tags: java, regex

I have a text file:

```
   @Entity
@Table(name = "User")
public class User implements LSLEntity, HasUUID {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "facebook_id", unique=true)
    private String facebookId;

    @UUID
    @Column(name = "uuid", unique = true)
    private String uuid;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_info_id")
    private UserInfo userInfo;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="balanced_customer_id")
    @Transient
    private BalancedCustomer balancedCustomer;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user")
    private Session session;

    public User(){
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFacebookId() {
        return facebookId;
    }

    public void setFacebookId(String facebookId) {
        this.facebookId = facebookId;
    }

    public UserInfo getUserInfo() {
        return userInfo;
    }

    public void setUserInfo(UserInfo userInfo) {
        this.userInfo = userInfo;
    }

    public BalancedCustomer getBalancedCustomer() {
        return balancedCustomer;
    }

    public void setBalancedCustomer(BalancedCustomer balancedCustomer) {
        this.balancedCustomer = balancedCustomer;
    }

    public Session getSession() {
        return session;
    }

    public void setSession(Session session) {
        this.session = session;
    }
```

I want to replace all the annotations on the other. such an annotation `@OneToOne`replaced by `@myAnnotation1`  and annotation `@Column(name = "id")` replaced by `@myAnnotation1(bla bla bla)`. in other words, to replace certain strings with annotations on the other line with annotations.

```
public StringBuffer clenFile(File file) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8"));
        StringBuffer sbRead = new StringBuffer();
        StringBuffer sbResult = new StringBuffer();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sbRead.append(line).append("\n");
        }
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?m)^(?! *@) *(.+)(\\s)").matcher(sbRead);
        while (m.find()) {
            sbResult.append(m.group(1)).append("\n");
        }
        return sbResult;
    }
```

This method cleans me the file from annotations. but lost margins. how to maintain margins, and replace these annotations to your own?

OUTPUT NOW:

```
public class User implements LSLEntity, HasUUID {
private Long id;
private String facebookId;
private String uuid;
private UserInfo userInfo;
private BalancedCustomer balancedCustomer;
private Session session;
public User(){
}
public Long getId() {
return id;
}
public void setId(Long id) {
this.id = id;
}
public String getFacebookId() {
return facebookId;
}
public void setFacebookId(String facebookId) {
this.facebookId = facebookId;
}
public UserInfo getUserInfo() {
return userInfo;
}
public void setUserInfo(UserInfo userInfo) {
this.userInfo = userInfo;
}
public BalancedCustomer getBalancedCustomer() {
return balancedCustomer;
}
public void setBalancedCustomer(BalancedCustomer balancedCustomer) {
this.balancedCustomer = balancedCustomer;
}
public Session getSession() {
return session;
}
public void setSession(Session session) {
this.session = session;
}
public void setUuid(String uuid) {
this.uuid = uuid;
}
public String getUuid() {
return uuid;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by this `This method cleans me the file from annotations. but lost margins. `? could you provide the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Through `string.replaceAll` function.

```
String input = "   @Entity\n" + 
                "@Table(name = \"User\")\n" + 
                "public class User implements LSLEntity, HasUUID {\n" + 
                "\n" + 
                "    @Id\n" + 
                "    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)\n" + 
                "    @Column(name = \"id\")\n" + 
                "    private Long id;\n" + 
                "\n" + 
                "    @Column(name = \"facebook_id\", unique=true)\n" + 
                "    private String facebookId;\n" + 
                "\n" + 
                "    @UUID\n" + 
                "    @Column(name = \"uuid\", unique = true)\n" + 
                "    private String uuid;\n" + 
                "\n" + 
                "    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)\n" + 
                "    @JoinColumn(name=\"user_info_id\")\n" + 
                "    private UserInfo userInfo;\n" + 
                "\n" + 
                "    @OneToOne\n" + 
                "    @JoinColumn(name=\"balanced_customer_id\")\n" + 
                "    @Transient\n" + 
                "    private BalancedCustomer balancedCustomer;\n" + 
                "\n" + 
                "    @OneToOne(mappedBy = \"user\")\n" + 
                "    private Session session;\n" + 
                "\n" + 
                "    public User(){\n" + 
                "    }\n" + 
                "\n" + 
                "    public Long getId() {\n" + 
                "        return id;\n" + 
                "    }\n" + 
                "\n" + 
                "    public void setId(Long id) {\n" + 
                "        this.id = id;\n" + 
                "    }\n" + 
                "\n" + 
                "    public String getFacebookId() {\n" + 
                "        return facebookId;\n" + 
                "    }\n" + 
                "\n" + 
                "    public void setFacebookId(String facebookId) {\n" + 
                "        this.facebookId = facebookId;\n" + 
                "    }\n" + 
                "\n" + 
                "    public UserInfo getUserInfo() {\n" + 
                "        return userInfo;\n" + 
                "    }\n" + 
                "\n" + 
                "    public void setUserInfo(UserInfo userInfo) {\n" + 
                "        this.userInfo = userInfo;\n" + 
                "    }\n" + 
                "\n" + 
                "    public BalancedCustomer getBalancedCustomer() {\n" + 
                "        return balancedCustomer;\n" + 
                "    }\n" + 
                "\n" + 
                "    public void setBalancedCustomer(BalancedCustomer balancedCustomer) {\n" + 
                "        this.balancedCustomer = balancedCustomer;\n" + 
                "    }\n" + 
                "\n" + 
                "    public Session getSession() {\n" + 
                "        return session;\n" + 
                "    }\n" + 
                "\n" + 
                "    public void setSession(Session session) {\n" + 
                "        this.session = session;\n" + 
                "    }";

        System.out.println(input.replaceAll("(?m)^(?: *@.*)?\\n|^ +", ""));
```

Output:

```
public class User implements LSLEntity, HasUUID {
private Long id;
private String facebookId;
private String uuid;
private UserInfo userInfo;
private BalancedCustomer balancedCustomer;
private Session session;
public User(){
}
public Long getId() {
return id;
}
public void setId(Long id) {
this.id = id;
}
public String getFacebookId() {
return facebookId;
}
public void setFacebookId(String facebookId) {
this.facebookId = facebookId;
}
public UserInfo getUserInfo() {
return userInfo;
}
public void setUserInfo(UserInfo userInfo) {
this.userInfo = userInfo;
}
public BalancedCustomer getBalancedCustomer() {
return balancedCustomer;
}
public void setBalancedCustomer(BalancedCustomer balancedCustomer) {
this.balancedCustomer = balancedCustomer;
}
public Session getSession() {
return session;
}
public void setSession(Session session) {
this.session = session;
}
```

Comment: no this is what I get. I expect as in the source file

Comment: i provided the expected output for the above example.. I don't know much about java. Consider writing the output to another file..